# when does $a\in\mathbb{R}$ does $\neg(a\leq 15\implies a>1)$ hold?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

How can I formally write down for which $a\in\mathbb{R}$ the statement  $\neg(a\leq 15\implies a>1)$ holds?

Comment: Rewrite $A\implies B$ to $\lnot A\vee B$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** An implication is false precisely when the hypothesis is true and the conclusion is false.

Answer (score 0):

Option #1:

- $\neg(a\leq15\implies{a>1})\iff$
- $\neg(\neg(a\leq15)\vee(a>1))\iff$
- $(a\leq15)\wedge\neg(a>1)\iff$
- $(a\leq15)\wedge(a\leq1)\implies{a\leq1}$

Option #2:

- $\neg(a\leq15\implies{a>1})\iff$
- $\neg(\neg(a\leq15)\vee(a>1))\iff$
- $\neg((a>15)\vee(a>1))\implies$
- $\neg(a>1)\iff{a\leq1}$